# Yii2: select2 with jQuery event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, jquery-select2

I am trying to trigger a function when a value of a Select2 is selected. The select2 has name of colors.

```
$('#idColor').on('select2:selecting', function(e) {
    console.log($('#idColor').val());
});
```

Example: I select the option Blue and nothing happened. Then I select the color Red and the console shows Blue.

The Select2 widget is in a Yii2 project created by another person. So I couldn't find its documentation web.

[image: Select2 example]

Maybe I have a similar problem to this, but this person use Backbone.js: [Click and Change event not working for jquery-select2 options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795313/click-and-change-event-not-working-for-jquery-select2-options)

I am learning jQuery, so maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors at all.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a duplicate, but it might be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615108/trigger-an-action-after-selection-select2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be you are not using the right event Try using onChange

```
 $('#idColor').on('change', function(e) {
     console.log($('#idColor').val());
 });
```